# Silverlight Application 5 working and bandwidth

Tags: silverlight-5.0

I just wanted to confirm, that if a build a silverlight application and the whole package including the dll consumed comes to 50 mb and then when user use this application in browser then does all the 50 mb app gets transfered over web? If yes then does there is any workaround for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the entire XAP file including the DLL(s) you have included will have to be downloaded. It is however possible to use the [application library caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833069%28VS.95%29.aspx) technique to make the download more efficient.

By checking the *Reduce XAP size by using application library caching* checkbox in the project *Properties* window, *Silverlight* tab, only the assemblies required at startup will be downloaded to begin with. Remaining assemblies (parts) are downloaded when required. The assemblies or parts will also be cached on the file system for later retrieval when the user revisits the Silverlight application.